# android - method in fragment is not able to access variables declared earlier

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, textview, nullreferenceexception

I've got a fragment:

```
public class VertretungsplanTab extends Fragment implements MainActivity.VertDataInterface{

    TextView vertretungsView;
    String LOG_TAG = VertretungsplanTab.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertretungsplan_fragment, container,false);
        vertretungsView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        vertretungsView.setText("initialised");
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefreshed(Fragment tab,String data){
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "interface is working");
        if(vertretungsView!=null) {
            vertretungsView.setText(data);
        }
        else{
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "TextView is null object");
        }
    }
}
```

The interface code is this in MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            VertDataInterface mdataInterface;
            private Fragment Vertretungstab;

            public interface VertDataInterface {
                public void onRefreshed(Fragment tab,String data);
            }
            private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
            private ViewPager mViewPager;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
                // primary sections of the activity.
                mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

                // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
                mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

                TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

                Vertretungstab = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
                try {
                    mdataInterface = (VertDataInterface) Vertretungstab;
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e + " fragment must implement VertDataInterface");
                }
            }

    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
                mdataInterface.onRefreshed(Vertretungstab,"cool");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    DashboardTab tabDashboard = new DashboardTab();
                    return tabDashboard;
                case 1:
                    VertretungsplanTab tabVertretungsplan = new VertretungsplanTab();
                    return tabVertretungsplan;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Dashboard";
                case 1:
                    return "Vertretungsplan";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And I've got a question:
Why am I not able to access my TextView inside my interface. why can i set the text in the onCreate method and why is it only getting a null object reference in the interface method?!

After searching the internet a long time I would be glad if a more advanced developer could get a solution!

Comment: provide your interface code please

Comment: I don't see your interface method here. I think you did something wrong in it.

Comment: try to add @Override annotation before the onRefreshed method inside your VertretungsplanTab class

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make any difference

Comment: Is your `textView2` is in `activity_main`? and not in `vertretungsplan_fragment`?

Comment: You need to implement interface correctly. You can create setter method of your interface object in activity and need to set listener in Fragment. like activity.setInterface(this);

Comment: is there a reason why you are adding the interface inside your mainactivity ? if not then split it into a different file

Comment: @Srikar Reddy My textview2 is in vertretungsplan_fragment.xml but I'm also using the interface to be executed in MainActivity to deliver some text to my fragment and then to put it there into a textView

Comment: @Artipatel I'm doing mdataInterface = (VertDataInterface) Vertretungstab; but if this is not what you mean or I should do pls give a more detailed answer on what to do!

Comment: @YamenNassif yes, because i want to transfer data from my MainActivity to my VertretungsplanFragment...

Comment: @JayJay you added this Log.v(LOG_TAG, "interface is working"); do you see this in the log out put ?

Comment: @YamenNassif Yes I do! And when I used a try catch method inside onRefreshed() I've got an null object reference error

Answer (score 1):

The method :

```
public void onRefreshed(Fragment tab,String data);
```

That is contained in **MainActivity.java** is not the same that is implemented in **VertretungsplanTab.java** .

In VertretungsplanTab you have :

```
public void onRefreshed(String data)
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
public void onRefreshed(Fragment tab, String data)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I was just a bit messy.
In my actual code this error wasn't present.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in mdataInterface.onRefreshed(Vertretungstab,"cool"); and check which instance is null

Comment: what do you mean?!

Comment: i mean that probably onRefresh is being called before fragment's onCreate runs ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i solved my problem...
I had to set the TextView variable to public static ...

```
public static TextView vertretungsView;
```